# Why eval() for JS code in server results in: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using AJAX to call the server, on server side when I eval a javascript code (forloop) inside the page (ajax.php) like below:

```
<?php
if($part==1){
?>
    for(var i=0; i<5;i++){
        alert(i);
    }
<?php
}
```

With the callback in Javascript page (ajax.js):

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        if(xmlHttp.status==200){
            if(xmlHttp.responseText!=''){       
                var sc = document.createElement('src');
                sc.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
                eval(sc.innerHTML);  // Error in first case (forloop in server)     
            }

        }
    }              
}
```

I get an error on chrome:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

While if I put the forloop code in the page ajax.js instead of ajax.php, everything works fine as below:

```
<?php
if($part==1){
?>
    execute();
<?php
}
```

Below the function execute() in ajax.js, everything works fine in this case

```
function execute(){
    for(var i=0; i<5;i++){
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

May I know please why this happen and how to prevent from this error?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: console.warn( xmlHttp.responseText) could help.

Comment: Confirm the response innerhtml is `"for(var i=0; i<5;i++){alert(i);}"`

Comment: Why on earth are you parsing Javascript as HTML in a non-existent element? In particular, `<` won't be what you think it is.

Comment: What's with `document.createElement('src');`?  What is an `<src>` element?

Comment: Probably because you are getting notice from PHP about undefined $part variable.

Comment: @megawac: it is not working too :(

Comment: @SLaks: I am using eval to parse the response from the server which is for(var i=0; i<5;i++){alert(i);}. I am creating an script element and put the server response inside that element then call eval! The second case is working fine! What shall I do to get it working in first case?

Comment: Oh guys sorry! I should use document.createElement('script') instead of 'src'! Thank you very much @JamesMontagne

Comment: Still, your approach is too convolute - create a `script` tag, then set its `src` attribute to your PHP script path, done.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The problem was I was creating a script element using document.createElement('src') instead of document.createElement('script'). I am sorry!

Thank you very much all!

Comment: If you are using eval to execute the code, there is no need to create a script element at all, just eval the code. Using the innerHTML property for script is problematic. Alternatively, avoid using eval and assign the response as the *text* property of the script element.